# How to fix wrong link in CONTRIBUTING.md in a github repository?

Tags: github

When you have a github repository you might have a file `CONTRIBUTING.md` which describes how users can contribute to this project.

In a file `CONTRIBUTING.md` in one of our groups repositories the following raw text

```
Please do not hesitate to raise an issue on [github project page][github].
```

creates the text

```
Please do not hesitate to raise an issue on github project page.
```

where `github project page` is a link that leads to a *different* github repository!

So the internal link `[github]` (or what this is) leads to a different repository. I also do not understand what the two square brackets together mean

```
[github project page][github]
```

as a link usually is created with a [normal and a square bracket](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax)

```
[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)
```

The project has been renamed, but the link leads to a completely different github repository.

How can I fix this? How can I change the link of the internal link `[github]`? Or where can I find documentation about this feature?

Comment: This will do the work `# Got A Question`, this will create a heading but also when hover on this heading on the left side you can see a link icon. just click on it and on your URL bar you will see `someurl#got-a-question`

Comment: Ah right, those are internal links! I forgot or did not know. 

But still, why does the link `[github]` leads to a different github repository?

Comment: it's markdown syntax, like if you are using same link multiple times in a markdown, you can just define a sort of variable which will hold that url and then you can use that variable to refer to that URL. see in the bottom of the file there will be something like `[github]: myURL`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is a kind of *reference* defined at the end of the file!

So for the above example you can define this reference at the end of your file as follows:

```
[github]: https://github.com/YourGroup/YourRepo
```

Not sure this is documented.